# getting information of a facebook friend

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph api to obtain friend list. Once I receive an id of friend using /me/friend, now I wish to obtain further information. Code I wrote for it is:

```
$fr = $app->facebook->api('/'.$uid);
echo $fr['id'];
```

Though it gives error. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error does it give you? That might give us a clue as to what went wrong. most errors from graph are because you haven't authenticated properly.

Comment: OK. Maybe I was in a wrong direction. The error as I checked was about crossing the maximum execution time. But then how do I process friends without crossing limit? FQL?

Comment: That just sounds like php timed out trying to make the call - either you have a network problem or facebook is down ( which is surpisingly likely )